# Expand div to full height in cell with rowspan

Tags: html, css

I need to expand `div` inside CELL 1 (rowspaned) to full height by using pure CSS only.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan='3'>
      <div>cell 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the height of the table cell is not defined.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div {
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I confess that I didn't understand why to set the table size to 100%... But it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/w3fhjykz/4/] Now I need vertically center text "Cell 1"... I tiyed with "vertical-align: middle;" but didn't work...

Comment: I got it with "display: flex;"...

Comment: This url does not exist. If you don't mind, could you check the answer?